# How to write Mockito testcase for HashMap using Junit5?

Tags: java, hashmap, mockito, junit5

I am new to Junit. Need to write the testcase for below code which is a  HashMap. connData is a Hashmap object which gets info from notificationObj, obj and passing that to sendAll() method.

```java
public void sendAllNet(Notifications obj, NotificationConfig config) throws Exception {
    HashMap<String, String> connData = new HashMap<String, String>();

    connData.put("mobiles",
            obj.getData().get("numbers").toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", ""));
    connData.put("message", (String) obj.getData().get("message"));
    connData.put("route", "4");
    connData.put("key", (String)config.getData().get("key"));
    connData.put("id", (String) config.getData().get("id"));
    connData.put("url", (String) config.getData().get("url"));

    sendAll(connData);
}
```

Comment: What do you want to mock? If 'conDition' then you should move it to separate method that you can than mock.

Comment: Please follow guidelines how to ask questions

Comment: usually we should not be mocking any collection object, we should be creating actual object of map with test data in test class and pass that object to actual class. And in your case you should mock Notifications obj, NotificationConfig config classes and stub respective get calls

Comment: There doesn't seem to be much need for mocking here. As we do not know anything about `Notifications` and `NotificationConfig`, mocking them might be an option, but you might also be able to easily create those objects yourself. Assuming that `sendAll` is another public method of the same class `spying` on it and capturing the hashmap with an `ArgumentCaptor` might also be an option, however the usual recommendation would be that you might want to move the `sendAll` method to a dependency that can be mocked instead.